# Why two settings for Instant Apps on Android?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm using a Pixel 3 running Android 11. I found 2 different settings that control some aspect of Instant Apps:

1. Settings / Apps & Notifications / Default apps / Opening Links / Instant Apps (open links in apps even if they’re not installed) - Switch defaulted ON
2. Google Play / Profile photo / Settings / General / Google Play Instant / Upgrade web links (switch defaulted off)

What does each control?

Comment: Did you figure out why that's the case?

Comment: Also bumped into the same thing, did either of you end up figuring it out?